# Laravel upsert only if two columns conflict

Tags: mysql, laravel, upsert

I have the following table

```
id | invoice_id | position | item_name | qty
---|------------|----------|-----------|----
 1 |    1234    |   200    |   shaft   | 2
 2 |    1234    |   202    |   spear   | 1
 3 |    1235    |   200    |   shaft   | 10
 4 |    1235    |   202    |   spear   | 20
```

How can I "target" to update the first row (`id` is `1`) only if `invoice_id` AND `position` match? If I would add a new item with `position` 500 for the `invoice_id` of 1234, it would insert a new row, otherwise if `position` is 200 or 202, it would update the existing (name or qty)?

I have seen the laravel's v8 `upsert()` function but it needs only one unique identifying column, and not in this case two.

Comment: the example in the docs for upsert is using 2 columns to identify the records, "the second argument lists the column(s) that uniquely identify records within the associated table." ... the issue is the columns need some type of index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the method `updateOrCreate()`. First parameter is the condition of unicity, the second paramerter is the reste of the attributes. It's the single row version of `upsert()`

```
Model::updateOrCreate(
    ['invoice_id' => '1234', 'position' => '500'],
    ['qty' => 5, 'item_name' => 'shaft']
);
```

`upsert()` is not limited to one unique column

```
Flight::upsert([
    ['invoice_id' => '1234', 'position' => '500', 'qty' => 5, 'item_name' => 'shaft'],
    ['invoice_id' => '1234', 'position' => '600', 'qty' => 10, 'item_name' => 'shaft']
], ['invoice_id', 'position'], ['qty']);
```

First parameter is for entries, second is for a list on identifying column and Thrid parameter is for the updated fields if a match is found.

> All databases systems except SQL Server require the columns in the second argument provided to the upsert method to have a "primary" or "unique" index.

To be able to use the `upsert` method, you need to add a `unique` constraint on the composite key made out of `invoice_id` and `position`

Comment: What If I want to insert two positions, let's say, `500` and `600` at the same time? Would this still work?

Comment: @TheVaLo if you want to mass updateOrCreate, then use upsert. more details in the answer

Comment: @N69S I am facing issues with upsert.My schema looks like this $table->unique([column1,column2,column3,column4],unique_name).As you can see, I have unique in array with 4 columns.BUt upserts always adding not updating.Any idea on this ?

Comment: @ira you should add more details in a seperate question with examples you tried. anyway it should work if all four column value already exists in your DB and you put them all in the second array of `upsert()`

Comment: @N69S I really dont know what the reason, but deleting the db and re running migrations  solves the issue